# Need Java Annotation to enforce javac -source option at compile time

Tags: java, annotation-processing

We have some general utility classes in our large Java codebase that have to be deployed as a library in an environment where Java 1.6 is the only option. When this library is built, on infrequent occasions, we compile them with a Java 8 compiler with the -source option set to 1.6. The problem is, we've had to deal with compile errors that occur because someone has added code to the classes that use 1.7 or later Java language features. This happens because during the course of normal development, this code is developed and deployed in a Java 8 environment.

What I'm wishing for is a built-in annotation that will cause compilation to fail if it contains any code that is not 1.6-compatible, regardless of the compiler version in use or the runtime version it's targeting. Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to exist. Would it be possible to create a custom annotation for this? None of the literature I've found on custom annotations talks about creating custom annotations that do their thing at compile time.

Comment: Annotation is the wrong thing... You don't want that. Probably not even possible. Use maven enforcer plugin.

Comment: https://www.mojohaus.org/extra-enforcer-rules/enforceBytecodeVersion.html

Comment: Custom annotations don't, themselves, do *anything*.  Annotations do not have behavior; they are just data.  Annotation-associated behaviors are implemented by separate components, including some built into Java compilers.  There's not much that such components can do with annotations they do not recognize.